# Robocopy to multiple destinations

Tags: robocopy

is it possible and safe to copy from one source to multiple destinations with Robocopy?

I mean, something like this in a bat file:

```
ROBOCOPY source dest_1
ROBOCOPY source dest_2
```

Is there any side effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, go right ahead.  This is exactly the sort of thing robocopy is good at.

Answer (score 2):

This might be of help: http://robomojo.codeplex.com

It's a free and open source shell for Robocopy.  It lets you set up "tasks" (i.e: a single Robocopy command) and combine them into "Jobs" (multiple tasks) which run in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this will not work if you are using the `/mon` option.

Comment: Not really understanding the downvote here? If somehow has a way to make robocopy kickoff multiple actions in one batch file with "/mon" activated. I would be thrilled!